# How do I Print a .pdf document from the apps documents directory

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I'm trying to pull a .pdf from my apps documents directory and load it in the PIC. The PIC displays without errors but shows no data in the preview.
What am I missing here? Am I just taking a completely wrong approach?

```
-(IBAction)actPrintPDF:(id)sender
{


NSString* fileName = @"Observation.PDF";

NSArray *arrayPaths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSLog(@"Path = %@",path);
NSLog(@"pdfFileName = %@",pdfFileName);

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

print.delegate = self;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = [pdfFileName lastPathComponent];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
print.printInfo = printInfo;
print.showsPageRange = YES;
print.printingItem = myData;
UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.view viewPrintFormatter];
viewFormatter.startPage = 0;
print.printFormatter = viewFormatter;


UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {};

[print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

The log is showing this:
***2015-11-08 08:56:30.462 ShortShooter4[16153:7505181] Path = /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02F8C004-6BA3-4F7B-9FC4-743DA205D7DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/796A70BC-4159-4B18-825E-B35043BC5704/Documents

2015-11-08 08:56:30.462 ShortShooter4[16153:7505181] pdfFileName = /Users/muUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02F8C004-6BA3-4F7B-9FC4-743DA205D7DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/796A70BC-4159-4B18-825E-B35043BC5704/Documents/Observation.PDF
2015-11-08 08:56:31.080 ShortShooter4[16153:7505181] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .***

So I can see the document is there. I also have the unbalanced calls issue but I'll attack that separately.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by removing:

```
UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.view viewPrintFormatter];
viewFormatter.startPage = 0;
print.printFormatter = viewFormatter;
```

Hope This helps someone else.